# Individual CSS Class Not Changing Styles with Media Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've got a page I'm building for a client in Leadpages that is due tomorrow.

Before I begin, I apologize for how long this is. I'm trying to make sure I have all the info. I've searched for an answer and haven't found one.

**The problem is,** for some reason I can't get the contact section (on the right side of the page) to apply my styles. The confusing part is, it only happens within my media queries.

I've checked my media queries over several times, and see no errors.

I ran my HTML through an HTML linter, and my CSS through a CSS linter. No problems their either.

Perhaps what is **even weirder is I can't replicate the problem over in Codepen or JSFiddle.** Only on the page.

To test how it is working, I have a display of none set for that contact section at a max-width of 670px. For some reason, Codepen and JSFiddle are hiding the contact section before this media query, and showing it after the media query.

I do not understand what is going wrong. I just want to find out how to resolve the issue with my styles not applying for the contact section on mobile.

Each time I test things, I fall into a new problem.

**UPDATE: Hey all, it looks like it must have been the system taking a while to update or something. It finally decided to work thankfully! I tried clearing my cache again, like Jenuel was suggesting, and it started working.**

This is the code I'm using... https://jsfiddle.net/JoyfullyDeveloped/z4f1c7Lo/12/

**HTML**

```
<div class="contact-container">
<img class="headshot" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LZcoTszwiJtn_7ynVmgoKhdJev6ADFdxFWQY_6jd4iAZtvSPClZLeYpcJjT54vIhTQdvqZH9ri7jucSx70ktsg=w435">

<div class="contact">
<img class="contact-pic" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Db_erckwx5QElAB_PyEHdmaSMnaLPbMvAeYqk7_Cg7xKR-EbODou0cRfvrcRvOiDBP7DCSHEAEvh0NY96vsz=s0">
<p class="contact-section-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tenetur eius, at perspiciatis nihil accusamus voluptatibus animi architecto sunt quas blanditiis veritatis, excepturi, recusandae omnis voluptatem. Harum veritatis alias porro sed.</p>

<p>MAX MUSTERMANN</p>
<p>TELEFON: +49 (0) 666 6666 666</p>
<p>EMAIL: INFO@INFO.DE</p>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.headshot {
max-width: 700px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
left: -362px;
}

.contact {
float: right;
max-width: 460px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 500px;
position: relative;
top: -1070px;
}

.contact-pic {
width:200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1820px) {
.headshot  {
position:relative;
left:-316px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:1735px) {
.headshot {
position:relative;
left:-270px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:1640px) {
.headshot {
position:relative;
left:-224px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:820px) {
.headshot {
position:relative;
left:-178px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
.headshot {
position:relative;
left:-132px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:670px) {
.headshot {
position:relative;
left:-86px;
}
.contact {
display: none;
}
}
```

**Even the head-shot positions don't seem to be adjusting in the media query.** However, that only happens for the media queries of 820px or lower.

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache then reloading it again? or their might be a problem in your @media screen (max-width: 670)? like in .contact{ display: none; }

Comment: and what do you mean by this "right side of the head-shot to apply my styles.".. do you need to can you atleast ad a picture of the expected result?

Comment: Jenuel, Thank you for your reply! What I mean by that, is on the right side of the screen. Sorry for the confusion! I wrote it out weirdly by mistake.

Comment: have you tried using @media screen and (min-width:1820px),,, so that window min and above 1820px will be styled

Comment: @Colton Always put media queries at last. Here can u put the .contcat style just above the media queries and try?

Comment: UPDATE: Hey all, it looks like it must have been the system taking a while to update or something. It finally decided to work thankfully! I tried clearing my cache again, like Jenuel was suggesting, and it started working.